# How to get rid of duplicate code in derived classes?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overriding

I have a class hierarchy like:

```
class A {    
    list<A*> children;
public:
    void update() {
        do_something();
        update_current();
        for(auto child : children)
            children->update();
    }
protected:
    virtual void update_current() {};
};

class B : public A {
protected:
    void update_current() override {
        do_something_important();
    };
};

class C1 : public B {
protected:
    void update_current() override {
        B::update_current();
        do_something_very_important();
    };
};

class C2 : public B {
protected:
    void update_current() override {
        B::update_current();
        do_something_very_important_2();
    };
};

int main() {
    A* a = new A();
    //fill a's childred list somehow
    while(come_condition) {
        //some code
        a.update();
        //something else
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The question is: how can I remove duplicate `B::update_current();` calls from derived classes without changing program's behaviour? Is it possible or are there no solutions except calling base class functions manually? Thank you.

Comment: Check the [Template Method Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html) please.

Comment: Two things: Firstly, you don't have duplicate code in derived classes but you have code in the baseclass that is properly reused in derived classes. Secondly, since `A::update_current()` is empty and `A::update()` is never called, I wonder what that class should illustrate. I'd suggest you rework your question a bit.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I updated the question as you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

You could make `B`'s children override a different function:

```
class B : public A {
protected:
    void update_current() override final {
        do_something_important();
        do_something_important_later();
    };

    virtual void do_something_important_later() = 0;
};
```

With:

```
class C2 : public B {
protected:
    void do_something_important_later() override {
        do_something_very_important_2();
    };
};
```

Comment: I thought about it, but what if i have more that 3 classes in hierarchy? Like 4 ot 5? In that case I will have to make a new name to the function every time I create another class.

Comment: @Satus Why would you need a new name every time you create another class? All of `B`'s descendants just need to implement `do_something_important_later()`. That's one name.

Comment: I would need it if `B`'s descendants need to call `B`'s method too (like `C` calles `B`'s `update_current`).

Comment: @Satus Reread my answer. All of `B`s descendants will call `B`s method.

Comment: I understand. I meant, what if `C`'s descendants will have to create their own update methods, but with calling `B`'s and `C`'s method too?